# Three dimensional test for uniformity and chi squared statistic

Tags: r

I have a homework problem that requires me to calculate the chi squared statistic from scratch in R. The first part of the problem requires that a data set be randomly generated from U[0,1] and then a list of successive triples be formed. The third part of the question states that we need to count the number of triples that fall in each of the 1000 cubes of side 0.1 that cover the unit cube. I am really confused about this third part of the question. How do we create a count for the number of triples falling  in each of the 1000  cubes  of a given side  length?  Graphically I  understand what this should be like, but  have no idea  how to program it. Any help or suggestion on this will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Have you tried coming up with an algorithm? That is, instead of asking yourself "how can I do this in R?" you might want to start by asking yourself "what do I actually want the computer to do?" and then writing out a series of steps in words.

Comment: You should have a look at the algorithm in `chisq.test` and `runif` to generate the data

Comment: Use three dimensional arrays, the *cubic matrices*.

Comment: For the algorithm, this is what I can think of intuitively, I will need to place triples in cubes where the volume of each cube is 0.001 and the triples need to be added until the cumulative sum of volumes of the triples added is equal to the volume of each cube. This would give the number of triples required to fill each cube. We carry out this process iteratively for each of the 1000 cubes until the set of triples is exhausted. This is how I am thinking of the algorithm but not sure if I am correct here